# Laravel 5 Eloquent, double one-to-one save (get Id before save)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

```
$profile = new Profile;
$user = new User;

$user['profile_id'] = $profile['id'];
$profile['user_id'] = $user['id'];

$profile->save();
$user->save();
```

So I have the relationships setup using "hasOne" in both Models files. These are NOT NULL FOREIGN KEYS so I need to define the id relationship immediately. But ['id'] is not available until after save. How can I do these 2 save operations at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the foreign key in only one of the tables, and define the other relationship as belongsTo

EDIT

If you keep the user_id in the profiles table, then add this to your user model

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

then you can do this

```
$user = new User;
$user->save();
$user->profile()->save(new Profile());
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. If you don't add some code to this I will for people who stumble on this page in the future ( I seriously couldn't find a duplicate)

Comment: Go ahead and add in an edit if you want. I think its more of a database design mistake.

Comment: Well this is a simplified example. Yes a profile should probably belong to a user. I'm still unclear on the syntax of the save. and I think an example to counter the code I provided will be helpful